# A problem on prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Investigating a special finite group, I encountered the following problem on primes: Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes and suppose $p^n=q^2+q+1$. It seems that the exponent $n$ here must be $1$. However, except some special cases, I was not able to find a proof.

Comment: Multiplicate both sides of the equation with q-1.

Comment: I already did it. But it was not useful.

Comment: Sven Wirsig possibly suggests Catalan's conjecture: Except 8 and 9 no two consecutive numbers can be powers of natural number (power means at least a square). See the Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

Comment: Actually I can't understand what is the connection between this problem and the Catalan conjecture.

Comment: Sorry, I had something different in mind but it does not fit here.

Comment: full solution here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206931/what-is-prime-power-of-this-equation-of-p/

Comment: thank you, I saw the solution.